# which fileappender should be used to create new log files depending on size of the log file

Tags: java

i have a requirement where i should log data in to logging file,where a new loglife should be created every time if the size of the present log file exceeds 1 MB .

How do i acheive the requirement in java.

Comment: what kind of log do you have ? do you log manually or use logger like log4j?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use RollFileAppender as like this If you use log4j

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
         <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/<logFile>.log"/>
         <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1MB"/>
         <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="100"/>
         <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
              <param name="ConversionPattern"
                         value="[%d{dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss:sss z}] %5p %c{2}: %m%n" />
         </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Selvakumar:thanks a lot solution is working perfectly with my scenario

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/). For creating new log file based on size you need to use [org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html)